# PHP Different Query Results - MySQL Workbench vs PHP Execution

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mysql-workbench

I'm running the following query using MySQL workbench and I'm getting the exact results from the database :

```
SELECT * 
FROM ODB_RG 
WHERE fullAddressV1 = 'רמת גן חרושת 1' 
    OR fullAddressV2 = 'רמת גן חרושת 1' 
    OR fullAddressV3 = 'רמת גן חרושת 1' 
    OR fullAddressV4 = 'רמת גן חרושת 1'
```

On the other hand, running the following php code does, that actually generated an equivalent query to the one mentioned above,does not return any record :

```
$fullAddress = "1 רמת גן חרושת";
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ODB_RG WHERE fullAddressV1 = :address1 "
        . "OR fullAddressV2 = :address2 OR fullAddressV3 = :address3 "
        . "OR fullAddressV4 = :address4");

$stmt->bindParam(':address1',$fullAddress);
$stmt->bindParam(':address2',$fullAddress);
$stmt->bindParam(':address3',$fullAddress);
$stmt->bindParam(':address4',$fullAddress);

$status = $stmt->execute();
```

The only reasonable cause that might lead to the difference between the solution is the Hebrew string that is passed as a parameter.

Any of you have any idea what should be done in order to fix it ?
Thanks in advance !

**EDIT :**
This is the collation i'm using for the relevant table:

```
engine=MyISAM charset=UTF8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: What collation do your database/tables/columns use? Use UTF8 if you are not sure.

Comment: Does your configuration support the character set that you are attempting to use?

Comment: OT: instead of repeating the address string, you can write `WHERE :address IN (fullAddressV1, fullAddressV2, fullAddressV3, fullAddressV4)`.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, what do you mean by configuration ? Where in code should I set it ? Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar , you're right, but as for now that is not my problem.

Comment: Hence the "OT:" prefix....

Comment: Also check the collation of your columns too - if they are out of whack that will cause problems.

Comment: @halfer, I think that if wrong columns collation was the problem, I would not get any records from the MySQL Workbench execution.Am I wrong ?

Comment: I don't know, but don't let that stop you checking.

Comment: @Itamar you get any results, what about error checking do you do any

Comment: @meda, could you please extend ?

Comment: Just as a "dumb" idea: does your code alogn with `$fullAddress = "1%";` return anything?

Comment: @dognose, does not return anything.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I meant by error checking:

```
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$fullAddress = "1 רמת גן חרושת";
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM ODB_RG WHERE fullAddressV1 = :address1 "
        . "OR fullAddressV2 = :address2 OR fullAddressV3 = :address3 "
        . "OR fullAddressV4 = :address4");

if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($con->errorInfo());
    die();
}

$stmt->bindParam(':address1',$fullAddress);
$stmt->bindParam(':address2',$fullAddress);
$stmt->bindParam(':address3',$fullAddress);
$stmt->bindParam(':address4',$fullAddress);

$status = $stmt->execute();

if (!$status ) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($con->errorInfo());
    die();
}
if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
   var_dump($row);
}else{
   echo 'no row found';
}
```

I know its ulgy, sometime called defensive programming, but it lets you know whats going on.

Comment: First of all , thanks for the answer. I've check it , no errors and no results.

Comment: @Itamar try hardcoding the values into the string directly

Comment: Tried that also, still no results. It's driving me crazy

Comment: @Itamar I dont see any other reasons than unicode, everything needs to be utf8 the column, the connection and even the php file itslef

Comment: @Itamar read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through